# Huawei k4203 HSPA+ dongle install help

Tags: internet, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

I have Ubuntu 12.10

Have Huawei k4203 USB broadband dongle and although there are instructions for linux , they don't work.

Here are the instructions:

```
(1) Insert stick
(2) Dismiss all popups about running the auto install scripts(they can't work)
(3) Open terminal
(4) cd $HOME
(5) mkdir vmb
(6) cd vmb
(7) (cd "/media/QuickStart ”?.0 && tar -cf - .) | tar -xf -
(8) chmod +x autorun.sh install_linux
(9) sudo ./autorun.sh
(10) Type user password
(11) Wait for last command to finish, then close terminal
```

All steps up to step 6 seam like something is happening, but after entering line 7 the terminal changes to a `">"` and then I copy/paste steps 8,9 and enter 10, but nothing happens.

How to solve this?

Comment: Is there a file called `install` in the dongle file folder?

Comment: If so you can install it by `chmod +x install` and then `sudo bash install` commands.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have unmatched quotations, and Ubuntu is awaiting the closure. I see that the closing quotation is different. If you just copy pasted that might explain why.